# Retrieve cell value of dynamically created table in ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html-table

I am adding rows to a  dynamically created table through javascript and I wanted to get its values on postback.

Here's the table:

```
<table id="summ" width="350px" border="1" >
```

Javascript snippet to add rows:

```
 $('#summ > tbody:last').append('<tr><td><input type="button" id="delete" value="Delete"></td><td>' + sup + '</td><td>' + qty + '</td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>');
```

How do I get the values of the cells appended to the table after a button is clicked? "summ" is not recognized because if I put `runat=server` on the table tag, the Javascript doesn't work.

Comment: What value of cell you want to post? Are these **sup** and **qty**? Use $.post to request and send data.

Comment: @AVD Yes, those variables. Will I be able to access those in the code behind? Sorry, I'm really new to javascript.

Comment: I've posted sample that might help you out. Post relevant code if any issue.

Comment: As an aside, if you do use `<table id="summ" runat="server" ... />` and this is an inline script, just be sure to "inject" the client id into your javascript: `$'#<%= summ.ClientID %> > tbody:last').append(...);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may define AJAX (WebMethod) method in code behind (add reference of System.Web.Services) and use $.ajax or $.post to request it. Have a look at code-snippet I've posted for your reference.

Sample.aspx (Code inline)

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Services" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<script runat="server">
    [WebMethod]
    public static string SendData(string sup,string qty)
    {
        return "OK : " + sup + " " + qty;
    } 
</script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Sample Page</title>
    <script src="../script/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var sup1 = 10; 
            var qty1 = 20;
            $("#btn1").click(function () {
                var arg = '{sup: ' + sup1 + ',qty:' + qty1 + '}';
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Sample.aspx/SendData",
                    data: arg,
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (msg) {
                        alert(msg.d);
                    },
                    error: function (msg) {
                        alert("Error: " + msg);
                    }

                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
       <input type="button" id="btn1" value="Save" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

If you want to use "runat" attribute then add an empty  inside the  and write ClientID attribute.

```
<table  runat="server"  id="summ" width="350px" border="1" >
 <tbody>
   <tr></tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

jQuery code

```
$("#<%=summ.ClientID%> > tbody:last").append('<tr><td><input type="button" id="delete" value="Delete"></td><td>' + sup1 + '</td><td>' + qty1 + '</td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>');
```

OR

Comment: what if there are 5 rows in each the supp and qty columns? how do i post all those 5 rows?

Comment: @PodMays - In that case you have to send json object that contains values - Refere SO thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645700/sending-a-json-object-to-an-asp-net-web-service-using-jquery-ajax-function What I suggest that you should try jQuery plugins - jqgrid and many more - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159025/jquery-grid-recommendations

Answer (score 2):

The server has no idea you were mucking about with the DOM.
You can send the values back using HiddenFields:

```
var sup = "test";
var qty = 123;

$('#summ > tbody:last').append('<tr><td><input type="button" id="delete" value="Delete"></td><td>' + sup + '</td><td>' + qty + '</td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>');
$('#HiddenField_sup').val(sup);
$('#HiddenField_qty').val(qty);
```

At the server:

```
Response.Write(HiddenField_qty.Value);
Response.Write(HiddenField_sup.Value);
```