# How to manipulate JSON type in web server?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, web-services

Hi I am making ajax call from browser to web service. The data is sent as JSON from browser to 
web service. I need to make a CLR type for a wrapped json object. Is there any other way to get it as string and deserialize into anonymous type in web server?

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results

Comment: In short, yes. There's always a way to do something different. Examples are important for questions like this, specifically what you've tried and examples of what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

suppose you have json in given form

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "name": "A Jones",
         "id": "500015763"
      },
      {
         "name": "B Smith",
         "id": "504986213"
      },
      {
         "name": "C Brown",
         "id": "509034361"
      }
   ]
}
```

then make classes according to it

```
public class MyClass
{
    public List<User> data { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
}
```

and then make a method which accept a parameter of this class type. Or
simply go through this link [Sending a JSON object to an ASP.NET web service using JQUERY ajax function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645700/sending-a-json-object-to-an-asp-net-web-service-using-jquery-ajax-function)

Answer (score 0):

```
var Filters = {
    "ClassName": [{
        "searchByName": "0",
        "id": "20"
    }]
};


$("#SaveButton").click(function(){

Filters.ClassName[0].searchByName = $("#txtName").val();
Filters.ClassName[0].if = $("#ddlName").val();

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "handler_path",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify(Filters.ClassName),
        processData: false,
        success: function (data) {
            //Write your code here

        },
        error: function (data) {
            //Handle your error
        }
    });

});
```

You can get the data as JSON object on handler and can read it using with streamreader and then Deserialize and access all the values here.

Hope all above description will make sense for you!